# regular expression callable iterator get length

Tags: python, regex, iterator

suppose i have the following code:

```
>>> a = re.finditer("(?P<char>\w)","hello world")
>>> for i in a:
    print i.groupdict()


{'char': 'h'}
{'char': 'e'}
{'char': 'l'}
{'char': 'l'}
{'char': 'o'}
{'char': 'w'}
{'char': 'o'}
{'char': 'r'}
{'char': 'l'}
{'char': 'd'}
```

as you can see, there are results and everything is great! however, i want to be able to know the `len(a)` so i would do:

```
>>> len(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#79>", line 1, in <module>
    len(a)
TypeError: object of type 'callable-iterator' has no len()
```

my question is, how can i get the length of `a`, or more generally, how do i get the length of callable-iterator so i can know if there were any results before i parse them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to turn the iterable into a list to get the length:

```
len(list(a))
```

Note that this *consumes* the iterable, so you may not be able to iterate over it again. Store the `list(a)` result in an intermediary before calling `len()` on it to be able to reuse all the elements in the list still:

```
a = list(a)
len(a)
```

Comment: damn, i should just shoot myself in the foot, such a simple solution, i was tearing my hair out. thanks :)

Comment: In the case `list(a)` consumes too much memory and you really need just its length, use the simple and fast `sum(1 for j in a)`.

Comment: @eumiro that would not be good, since you empty a, and can then no longer use it. in fact - because it gets emptied, there is not much space different between a list of a, and a itself, since once its read to a list, it diminishes to nothing but a shell.

Comment: @InbarRose: That's why eumiro said *"and you really need just its length"*.